# HTML + JavaScript results textbox to a NaN error

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this little homework im struggling with. Everytime I declare a variable as parseFloat in Javascript. It just results the textbox a NaN. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bank Statement</title>
</head>
<body>

<center>
  <h1 style="font-size:43pt">Statement of Account</h1>

<p>

<form name=fr1>
Customer Name: <input type=text name=ct>
Account No. : <input type=text name=acct><br><br>


<table border=4>
<tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Debit</th>
    <th>Credit</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Last Balance</th>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input type=text name=b1></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Monthly Salary</th>
  <td><input type=text name=d2></td>
  <td><input type=text name=c2></td>
  <td><input type=text name=b2></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>ATM</th>
  <td><input type=text name=d3></td>
  <td><input type=text name=c3></td>
  <td><input type=text name=b3></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Refund</th>
  <td><input type=text name=d4></td>
  <td><input type=text name=c4></td>
  <td><input type=text name=b4></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>ATM</th>
  <td><input type=text name=d5></td>
  <td><input type=text name=c5></td>
  <td><input type=text name=b5></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Telephone Bill</th>
  <td><input type=text name=d6></td>
  <td><input type=text name=c6></td>
  <td><input type=text name=b6></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Total Movement</th>
  <td><input type=text name=d7></td>
  <td><input type=text name=c7></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table><br>

<input type=button value="Show" onclick=show()>
<input type=reset value="Clear">

</form>

<script language="javascript">
function show()
{
b1=document.fr1.b1.value;
b2=document.fr1.b2.value;
b3=document.fr1.b3.value;
b4=document.fr1.b4.value;
b5=document.fr1.b5.value;
b6=document.fr1.b6.value;

d2=document.fr1.d2.value;
d3=document.fr1.d3.value;
d4=document.fr1.d4.value;
d5=document.fr1.d5.value;
d6=document.fr1.d6.value;
d7=document.fr1.d7.value;

c2=document.fr1.c2.value;
c3=document.fr1.c3.value;
c4=document.fr1.c4.value;
c5=document.fr1.c5.value;
c6=document.fr1.c6.value;
c7=document.fr1.c7.value;


b1=parseFloat(b1);
b2=parseFloat(b2);
b3=parseFloat(b3);
b4=parseFloat(b4);
b5=parseFloat(b5);
b6=parseFloat(b6);

d2=parseFloat(d2);
d3=parseFloat(d3);
d4=parseFloat(d4);
d5=parseFloat(d5);
d6=parseFloat(d6);
d7=parseFloat(d7);

c2=parseFloat(c2);
c3=parseFloat(c3);
c4=parseFloat(c4);
c5=parseFloat(c5);
c6=parseFloat(c6);
c7=parseFloat(c7);

document.fr1.b2.value=(b1-d2+c2);
document.fr1.b3.value=(b2-d3+c3);
document.fr1.b4.value=(b3-d4+c4);
document.fr1.b5.value=(b4-d5+c5);
document.fr1.b6.value=(b5-d6+c6);

document.fr1.d7.value=(d2+d3+d4+d5+d6);
document.fr1.c7.value=(c2+c3+c4+c5+c6);
}
</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

So I dont know why it's giving me NaN. Any tips or info I missed?

EDIT: This is what im getting at NaN: http://gyazo.com/73ae7a6d0fbbf4500b7547425c367349
-- Notice that the Blance and Credit give the 2nd balance NaN

Comment: Where's the javascript part that you get NaN?

Comment: Your browser has a fully-featured debugger built into it. The best way to learn is to use that debugger, step through your code, look at the variables as it runs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in the code:

1. You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring your local variables.
2. You're parsing fields with blank values and not checking the result. `parseFloat("")` returns `NaN`.

If you declare your variables and check that you're not parsing blank fields, you won't have `NaN` slipping into things.

If you want to treat a blank field as 0, you can use [JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) for that:

```
b1 = parseFloat(b1) || 0;
```

---

Separately from those errors, any time you find yourself writing long lists of variable names like `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, etc., look at using a loop and/or arrays.

Comment: Sweet, it works using the || 0;  But I dont understand, isn't || means Or? So does this mean that the value im doing defaults it to 0 or what?

Comment: @Martyn: See the link for details. `||` means OR, but the result isn't `true` or `false`, it's the left-hand operand if it's "truthy" or the right-hand operand otherwise.